# Google Android API exceeds circle radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Basically what i'm trying to do is fetch all bars using the Google maps web service, and place markers for each of them on the map. I'm grabbing my current location and fetching all the bars around around me in a 5km radius (5000) meters.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+ gps.getLatitude() +","+ gps.getLongitude() +"&radius=5000&types=bar&key="+ GOOGLE_KEY +"
```

Here's the problem, I fetched in a 5000 meter radius from my house, when I draw a 5000 meter circle radius around my house the markers exceed the circle. The ones that are outside shouldn't appear correctly because they are outside the radius. Is there a reason for it?

[image: You can see this in this picture.]

Comment: Are you sure that your actual location and the location that the GPS is returning are the same?  If you move your circle just barely to the right and up a little bit you'll be within a 5km circle.  Also, are you sure your 5km circle is fully accurate?

Comment: Yeah man, that was the first thing I checked for. They're exactly the same. It's confusing because that should be working. They both use the same function from the same class, gps.getLatitude(); Also if I put a marker on the center of the circle it's exactly my house.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "Radar Search" instead? (Service URL is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/output)

Documentation is on this page: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: I just gave this a shot then, it gave me more results which is good. But some of them are still outside the radius. Here's a photo [link](https://scontent.fakl1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpl1/v/t34.0-12/12351227_1244592775566829_1721942992_n.jpg?oh=6a549000d20665fd3fcae1d6000abed2&oe=566BAA45)

Comment: Could it be that some of these bars are just located somewhere on the specific road and Google don't have the exact address? Then the bar pops up on the map on the road's half way when that road enters the circle anywhere in it's full length.